# Error in .checkXYnames(colnames(x)) : vectlongitude/latitude in the wrong order

Tags: r, raster, point, vector-graphics, r-sp

I have a vector and a raster loaded. the points all lie within the raster. However, I get a en error when I run the Hiking function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p81uE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUh0p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CopC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZnLW.png)

Output when i run

```
 lang_coord_sp_200000 <- lcsa_subr(dem, lang_coord_sp, 400000, 24)
```

I tried to change the order of Longitude and Latitude (then I got an error, that the points are now out of the raster extent). I also tried to rename Longitude and Latitude with no success.

Comment: Please share an minimal reproducible example with code, and not just images of code. no one is going to retype your functions to find the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.